# Problem after installion of NOD32 on xubuntu 12.04

Tags: antivirus

After installing the program nod32 antivirus I took this error every time I open console.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libesets_pac.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

I use X ubuntu 12.04

[image]

Any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After installing the program nod32 antivirus in ubuntu 12.04 I got this error every time I opened the console.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libesets_pac.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

You can try to do this (from [this page](http://www.prof-labs.ru/blog/nix/100) in Russian):

- Open `/etc/ld.so.preload`

  ```
  sudo nano -w /etc/ld.so.preload
  ```

  and delete the row `libesets_pac.so` and save it.
- Open `/etc/rc.local`

  ```
  sudo nano -w /etc/rc.local
  ```

  and just enter the line `/opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_daemon` and save, after restarting the system.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: In case the libesetspac.so was the only line in ld.so.preload should I leave the file empty? or delete the file?

Comment: @michel.iamit I just removed the entry and saved the file. Also, I didn't need to do anything with /etc/rc.local as it didn't exist. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 x64 with ESET NOD32 Antivirus 4 v4.0.90.0.

Answer (score 4):

This seemed to have fixed that issue for me on Ubuntu 11.10 x64

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.preload
```

change `libesets_pac.so` to `/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so`

Save and your error should stop.

([`Source`](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=310086))

Comment: This didn't work for me running Ubuntu 18.04 x64. See my comment under OmegaEvil's answer.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 x64 with ESET NOD32 Antivirus 4.0.93. I only encountered the described error in case I used sudo. all other commands and terminal open worked just fine without the *warning*.

Answer (score 1):

From the preload message , I believe you're installing the wrong architecture.

But if you're on a x64 system , it's unavoidable , since you could be running 32bit programs as well , so esets installs both architecture , which made 64bits program can't preload the 32bit library , 32bit's program can't load 64bit library.

The only way to get rid of this , is make all your system 32bits.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Linux Mint 17.3. I used the solution given here:
Open `/etc/ld.so.preload`, open this well

```
sudo nano -w /etc/ld.so.preload
```

and delete the row `libesetspac.so` and save, after.
Open `/etc/rc.local`, open this well

```
sudo nano -w /etc/rc.local
```

and just enter the line `/opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_daemon` and save, after restarting the system. Good luck--this should solve your problem.

Then the problem with the preload errors was solved.

Then I tested if eset was still working by creating the EICAR.COM virus:

Start a text editor. Enter the text:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

Save as EICAR.COM this should be recognised as a virus, but it wasn't.

The correct solution is:

Edit `/etc/ld.so.preload` as super user and change:

```
libesets_pac.so
```

to:

```
/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so
```

Save the file and the library will be preloaded for new processes. You should restart the system to make it active for all processes.

Source: https://forum.eset.com/topic/7097-log-in-show-ldso-object-libesets-pacso-from-etcldsopreload-cannot-be-preloaded-ignored/

Now I tested again if the creation of the EICAR.COM  virus would be recognised and action would be taken and it was.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 with NOD32, after installing Gcloud SDK the message appeared for every action related to the gcloud/kubectl commands.

I've tried replacing the entry with :
`/opt/eset/esets/lib/libesets_pac.so`

Saved the entry and restarted the system, did not work.
Removing the entry completely on ubuntu 18.04 x64 solved the issue.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following lines, fixed the problem for me. Solution seems simple and logical as well:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 //ads architecture information
sudo apt-get update //update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 //install the lib
sudo reboot // restart required
```